# Why did Hitler meet with Subash Chandra Bose in 1942?

Tags: nazi-germany, indian

I have [read](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1946515701)   that [Subash Chandra **Bosa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhas_Chandra_Bose) met Hitler in 1942, why did he help Bosa by liberating indian prisoners of war, what motive did Hitler have to help Bose and who suggest him to do this for ,the Indian Freedom Movement. Since there is no information to be found about Bose and this meeting, I would be interested if anybody can help me in this matter.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what you think is missing from, or incorrect about the relevant section of the [Wikipedia article on Subhas Chandra Bose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhas_Chandra_Bose#1941%E2%80%931943:_Nazi_Germany), and the sources cited there?

Comment: You might also find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Book name 'man india missed the most'

Comment: @yuvralsingh please place that information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Wikipedia article, Hitler motive was to utilize anything/anybody that would assist him in his conflict with the British.

As the article suggests, when it became clear that trouble in India would better serve his ally **Japan**, he was sent to the Japanese.

This is a typical case of someone who was treated as a puppet, who was only used in the intrest of others.

Comment: It was in the book of bosa that 'i am afraid that ,german  can change their mind any time and send their soldiers to another front before they can fight for india' amd later it prove correct no soldier from german gone to japan

Comment: @yuvrajsingh Yes, history has taught most (but not all) ,  that those that place themselfs under of the control of peaple more powerful and have another agenda, find themselves often in a worse position than before.

Answer (score 0):

### Ease the pressure in North Africa and foment rebellion in India

[Indian Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Legion), that fought for Germans in WW2, was mostly manned by Indian POW that were captured in [North Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Army_during_World_War_II#Middle_East_and_Africa). British Indian Army had 4th Indian Division there, with several brigades from 5th Indian Division and other formations. Having Bose, who was at that time one of prominent Indian leaders, second in prestige only to Gandhi (and perhaps not even to him) , on German side and calling Indian troops to switch sides was not insignificant. Due to the nature of North African theater, both sides could support only relatively small number of troops. Had the number of defections from Indian units increased, British would be forced to pull them back from front line. Keep in mind that Hitler met Bose in late May of 1942 (supposedly [May 29, 1942](https://scroll.in/article/928856/fiction-pick-what-happened-when-netaji-subhas-chandra-bose-met-hitler-read-this-re-creation)), just as [Battle of Gazala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gazala) was unfolding. It was last major offensive effort for Axis in North Africa (and at first their biggest success). At that point of time, any unreliability of Indian units could mean major defeat for British, defeat that would be hard to rectify latter.

Second, and more important strategic reason, was to try to organize rebellion in India. India was a jewel in crown of British Empire, and in time of war important source of raw materials. Hitler and Bose toyed about possible German penetration in Caucasus ([Fall Blau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_Blue) was to begin shortly) and latter to Iran and further east. But realistically, only help could come from Japan. I took some time to arrange operation between two subs (German U-180 and Japanese I-29) that were to meet in the middle of the ocean and transfer Bose to Japanese control. Even before Bose arrived Japanese were trying to organize [Indian National Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_National_Army), but only after he took control in summer of 1943 they were able to achieve some success. In the end, INA arrived at scene too late (early 1944) and in insufficient numbers (around 50 000 men) to change something significantly in the outcome of war. At that point of time other Indian leaders were aware that Axis are losing the war (Italy already capitulated, Germany on the defensive, Japan losing in the Pacific) so they avoided calling Indians to rise up against British rule . Therefore, INA remained limited both in men power and equipment (Japanese troops had precedent, and supply situation was already critical). Real fruits of Bose's work came only after his death, with trials against former INA members which actually helped pro-independence cause and created something of a legend from Bose and his men.